# What is the intended pull request rejection workflow in TFS/Team Services?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

my team and I are using Team Services with Visual Studio 2015. I understand the concept of a pull request, but the rejection and correction process is very blur.

MSDN falls short of covering this part on the main page regarding the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/git/pull-requests

Basically, when you reject a pull request, what's expected of the person that created it? Should he modify his branch and issue a new different request? or bring changes to his branch in a way that will make it appear under the current request? In the latter case, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More detailed description is placed here: [Conduct a Git pull request on Visual Studio Online](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/conduct-a-git-pull-request-on-visual-studio-online/)

> **Make changes on the source branch**
>
> To act on the feedback, the requestor revises the code on their dev
>   machine and pushes the changes so that reviewers can see them.

So the requestor need to update his code and push the changes into source branch. The code in the pull request will be updated automatically after new change is pushed.

Comment: OK so basically, the requestor pushes a new version of the branch undergoing a pull request? The rest of the behavior is blur. Does this create a new request or add to the current? Does the reviewer get notified through alerts? What does the interface looks like at that point. I originally fell on the link you provided, but I feel there's an hole at this level.

Comment: @Olograph It will update current pull request instead of creating a new one. The reviewer will receive an email notification with subject "New changes were pushed to the pull request" if they have create an alert for pull request in "Alerts" settings.